# Track new SMS messages with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to handle new SMS message on Android with Xamarin.
I'm using real device, not virtual.
My handler is:

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
...
}
```

And i'm programmatically registering receiver in main activity by:

```
RegisterReceiver(new SmsBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

In my code i'm adding priority to intent 10k+ (tried without this too). Also i've tried registering via config.
Receiver doesn't fire.
But if i register HEADSET_PLUG event it will fire without problems.
Permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[Android.App.IntentFilter(new []{ SMS_RECEIVER })]

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private const string SMS_RECEIVER = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    ...
}
```

BTW i haven't tested it but i am convinced that it's gonna work. Please, let me know how it goes (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this should work fine:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })] 
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    private const string Tag = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
    private const string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"; 

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.Info(Tag, "Intent received: " + intent.Action);

        if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;

        SmsMessage[] messages=Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent (intent);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
        {

            sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", messages[i].OriginatingAddress,
                Environment.NewLine,messages[i].MessageBody));
        }

    }
}
```